I only need to fit a straight line with an intercept of 0，How should I adjust the Siegelslopes method？
solve Ax=B， Not Ax+C=B
This method is not suitable for me.
scipy linregress: computing only scaling/slope parameter with intercept fixed at 0
I search the Doc,but did't get the method.
There is no more way to use it.Help me,thanks.

Why isn't the linked method suitable for you? What have you tried? Where are your data and code?

I just need the Siegelslopes Method,not other
